# clarification regarding std::random_shuffle to shuffle the vector

Tags: c++, vector, std, shuffle

I am begginer at C++ and would like to clarify something. I have a vector of strings and must shuffle it randomly.

I am trying to understand what are the differences between

```
std::random_shuffle(vector.begin(), vector.end());
```

```
int myrandom(int i) {
    return std::rand() % i;
}


std::random_shuffle(cards_vector.begin(), cards_vector.end(), myrandom);
```

Both seem to work fine as long as I call the following function at the beggining of my main.c

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

I have also found another solution on the internet which uses std::default_random_engine

```
    auto rng = std::default_random_engine{};
    std::shuffle(cards_vector.begin(), cards_vector.end(), rng);
```

However, the solution above always return the same shuffle, even when the random seed is called in main. I am not sure whether that is intended or not.

I appreciate if someone could clarify this to me.

Comment: Note that [`std::random_shuffle`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) have been removed in the C++17 standard in favor of `std::shuffle`.

Comment: `srand` has nothing to do with with the C++ random functionality. You need to seed the random engine. Example here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

Comment: Also note that [`std::srand`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/srand) is for the old C [`rand`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand) function.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude So it is recommended to use std:shuffle if possible?

Comment: @RetiredNinja If i comment the ```srand(time(NULL));``` code, It generates the same random every time I run the code. When I uncomment it, it generates a different one every time so it seems that it has an effect on std::random_shuffle. Or are we talking about 2 different things here?

Comment: @LukasPetrikas [std::random_shuffle](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) `1) The random number generator is implementation-defined, but the function std::rand is often used.` So if you want to have consistent results, you want to always pass a specific random number generator to it. And seed that random number generator correctly. `The reason for removing random_shuffle in C++17 is, that the iterator only version is usually depending on std::rand, which is now also discussed for deprecation`

Comment: `std::shuffle()` and `std::srand()` are unrelated.  To seed `std::default_random_engine`, a different mechanism is used (typically, `std::random_device`).

Comment: Okay I see now. I will look into ```auto rng = std::default_random_engine{};
    std::shuffle(cards_vector.begin(), cards_vector.end(), rng);``` then and see how to properly seed it.

Comment: `std::default_random_engine{std::random_device{}()}`

Comment: @Evg Thanks that seems like a good solution.  ```auto rng = std::default_random_engine{ std::random_device{}() };
    std::shuffle(cards_vector.begin(), cards_vector.end(), rng);```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function [std::random_shuffle](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) has two overloads. In short, that means you can call the same function with a different number of parameters.

- The version `std::random_shuffle(vector.begin(), vector.end());` calls an internal random generator which is defined by the implementation (compiler, operative system, standard libraries, ...). However, often it is internally used `std::rand`.

From the documentation:

> The random number generator is implementation-defined, but the function std::rand is often used.

- The version `std::random_shuffle(cards_vector.begin(), cards_vector.end(), myrandom);` uses an explicit random generator (that you define; that is, `myrandom`) which internally calls `std::rand`.

The function [std::rand](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand) (from C) generate a [*pseudo*-random number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator). It means that once you have set the *seed* it will generate (every time) the same number sequence. In other words, the sequence is deterministic depending on the initial value (called *seed*).

In order to set the seed (the initial value) for the `std::rand` you need to call the function `std::srand` which accepts the seed as argument.

The statement `srand(time(NULL));` is an old common trick to initialize the generator with a *"random"* (not actually) seed. Indeed, the function `time(NULL)` returns the current time which is supposed to be different every time is called.

Therefore, every time your program starts you set the seed with a different number and the generator `std::rand` will produce a difference sequence every time.

---

**Please Note That**: `std::random_shuffle` is an old C++ function and it has been deprecated. You should indeed use its replacement, that is, `std::shuffle`.

> However, the solution above always return the same shuffle, even when the random seed is called in main. I am not sure whether that is intended or not.

The rationale behind this is the same as above.

In that example you are using *another* (different from `std::rand`) pseudo-random number generator, that is `std::default_random_engine{}`. This generator is defaulted initialized with a default seed.

If you want to generate different results for different application run, you need to initialize the generator with a seed which is meant to be different every time your application starts.

A more correct code would be:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>

// ...

auto rng = std::default_random_engine{std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count()};
```